# How i Update the managed metadata field with one more value keep old value in that column

Tags: powershell, taxonomy

I want to add one more value from the termset in the existing column value using Powershell script.

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy")
$site = Get-SPSite http://invi28apps9c
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["KB"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets["IPS Document type"]     
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(100)
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq "Docset"}
$web = Get-SPWeb http://invi28apps9c/DemoTeamSite
$list = $web.Lists["KBDocument"]
$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$query.RowLimit = 2000
$caml = "<Where> 
        <Eq>
         <FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/>
         <Value Type='Computed'>.zip</Value>
        </Eq>
        </Where>"
$query.Query = $caml 

do
{
    $listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
    $spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
    foreach($item in $listItems)
    {
        $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;
        $taxField =     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["Document Type"]
        $taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem,$term)
        $spItem.Update()
    }
}
while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Taxonomy terms to a taxonomy field using PowerShell, we need to involve SharePoint Object Model from PowerShell, and then use the Object Model to add terms in a termstore to the field.

Below is the same code for your reference. Please add the logic in the For-Each method:

## Site Collection URL - Give your site collection url in quotation marks

```
 $TaxonomySiteUrl = "http://server"
```

## Access the termstore

```
$site = Get-SPSite $TaxonomySiteUrl
$web = $site.OpenWeb()

$list = $web.Lists["listName"]

$newItem = $list.Items.Add()

$targetField = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$newItem.Fields["Name of Taxonomy Field"]

$session = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
 $termstore = $session.TermStores[$targetField.SspId]
 $termSet = $termstore.GetTermSet($targetField.TermSetId)

$taxCollection = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValueCollection($targetField)

$termSet.GetAllTerms() | ForEach-Object {
 $taxonomyFieldValue = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyFieldValue($targetField)
 $taxonomyFieldValue.TermGuid = $_.Id
 $taxonomyFieldValue.Label = $_.Name
 $taxCollection.Add($taxonomyFieldValue)
 }

$targetField.SetFieldValue($newItem, $taxCollection)

$newItem["Title"] = "Item1" 
$newItem.Update()
```

[Source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4c63fff1-8681-42a1-9fd2-256f1f80935b/add-multiple-taxonomy-terms-in-a-taxonomy-field-using-powershell?forum=sharepointadminprevious)

Comment: i want a code for if the library consist zip file than update the managed metadata column with Docset term  and also contains old value

Comment: @lokeshkumar you should update your question to provide more details then.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167494/how-i-update-the-managed-metadata-field-in-document-library-for-only-zip-files for full details