# How I update the Managed Metadata Field in Document Library for only .Zip Files using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, managed-metadata, term-store

```
        <Code For Termset>
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy")
$site = Get-SPSite http://invi28apps9c
$session = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession($site)
$termStore = $session.TermStores["Managed Metadata Service"]
$group = $termStore.Groups["KB"]
$termSet = $group.TermSets["IPS Document type"]     
$terms = $termSet.GetTerms(100)
$term = $terms | ?{$_.Name -eq "Docset"}
```

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://invi28apps9c/DemoTeamSite
$list = $web.Lists["KBDocument"]

$query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
 $query.ViewAttributes = "Scope='Recursive'";
$query.RowLimit = 2000
 $caml = "<Where> 
  <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name='DocIcon'/>
     <Value Type='Computed'>.zip</Value>

  </Eq>
    </Where>"
 $query.Query = $caml 

  do
    {
$listItems = $list.GetItems($query)
$spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition = $listItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

foreach($item in $listItems)
{

    $spItem = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem]$item;


    $taxField =     [Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField]$spItem.Fields["Document Type"]


   $taxField.SetFieldValue($spItem,$term)
    $spItem.Update()
}
   }
  while ($spQuery.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)
```

This code override the all old value with new value i need a code to append the new value with oldone.

Comment: please solve this asap

Comment: We don't "solve" other users issues with specific answers. We learn by asking questions and giving answers in a general way. Please edit your first question if you have further details. Thank you!